# How to have a component without inherited css in Angular 6

Tags: css, angular, frontend, angular6

I have a project that uses Angular 6 and Bootstrap, and now, i need to create only one page that can be responsive for use in mobile devices. So, i need to create this page/component without any css inherited from the project. How can I do this? Once I create the page, it already have some tags like  and css classes that I just dont know where are them imported to this component

Answer (score 0):

An option would be setting the viewEncapsulation to ShadowDom

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-comp',
  templateUrl: './test-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-comp.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class TestCompComponent {}
```

But beware of the browser support. More about this:

- https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM
- and here you can find a polyfill if you need to support IE 11: https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs
- https://caniuse.com/?search=shadow%20dom

Comment: this removes even the CSS that I have in my './test-comp.component.css'. and other components like navBar and sideBar are still in there...